# How to use TEXT and VARCHAR in same MySQL table use interchangeably (Java)

Tags: mysql, varchar, spring-jdbc

I have a table with column VARCHAR to store incoming data(tcp data),
 90% of the time data will fit into VRACHAR however rest of the time incoming data can exceed the column , I’m planning to store it in a separate TEXT column rather than making exiting column to TEXT . 
Please note that data is always in hexadecimal format ( 0 –F)
Table :

```
Table_Id    ,VARCHAR- column,   TEXT- column
```

I’m  planning to abstract this information in java layer by querying a MySQL View which logically present only one column ‘message’ depending on

```
( `VARCHAR- column` !=null  ? “`VARCHAR- column`”: ‘TEXT- column’)  AS message
```

In MySql View

I would like to know any thoughts on this approach and any suggestion how to do this in java layer ,
at present I’m thinking of checking the length of incoming message(since hexadecimal data )  if it can’t fit in to my VARCHAR then store in in TEXT column.

Thanks

Comment: Why bother with this extra complexity? What's the point? Why not use a single text column?

Comment: What @MattBall said. Why complicate with varchar / text, the only difference between them is a byte or so that they append to hold the length of the data they store. I doubt it's optimal for you to optimize to save a byte or two every now and then.

Comment: @ Matt well no , as i said 90 to 95% its going to fit in Varchar , if you understand the performance impact on storing Varchar vs text tthen thats a huge impact as this table will store atleast 1 millions of messages per day

Comment: There is almost ZERO performance impact between varchar and text. I don't know where you pulled the performance "info". Also, 1 million per day is a mere 115 reqiests per second, shaving a byte or two per record isn't going to make it or break it. However, it's your project and your code so I guess you should do what you deem fit. Also, performance heavily depends on storage engine, its configuration and underlying hardware. text vs varchar - the smallest factor possible in the whole story.

Comment: @N.B Thnx for you reply , Applicate that , i do understand there is no difference in storage in innodb , but correct me wrong , certainly there is a different for select  from table  , As above table will have equal  amount of reads and write , it can grow to many millions as well

Comment: Ok, let's start from the beginning - you need to *understand* how `varchar` and `text` columns work and whether they impact performance by a huge margin. A `varchar` writes a number to its storage before writing data - that's how it knows how much data there is, hence variable character. `text` does the same, except it uses more bytes. 1 byte can store number up to 255, that's why you can always see varchar(255). 2 bytes can store double that and so on. This is why there's almost no performance difference (to the point you will feel it) if you use text instead varchar.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use larger `varchar` definition. Also, since you're saving hexadecimal representation of something, it means you can also use varbinary or blob types - you don't need the charset information, and this is what these columns store as well.

Comment: I'm with N.B. -- If anything, you will hurt performance.  Even with 95%.  You will definitely hurt disk space -- because you need both length fields, plus two NULL indicators.  That's instead of one length field (of 2 bytes), plus no NULL indicators.